# How should the bass tag be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass) is currently on 18 questions and used to describe many different contexts including:

- [bass guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27393/why-is-my-bass-making-a-buzzing-noise) (which already has a tag: [bass-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass-guitar))
- [bass vocals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/31962/not-sure-what-voice-type-i-have) (which already has a tag: [bass-voice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass-voice))
- [the bass's function/use in harmony and creating bass lines](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32222/how-do-you-write-a-corresponding-bassline-for-an-already-written-melody) (which is already covered in the tag: [harmony](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harmony))
- [bass frequencies](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24428/pa-system-what-type-of-speaker-for-that-punchy-bass)
- [bass instruments or bass ranges of instruments](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14159/linking-organ-pedals-to-a-keyboard)

And the tag info for bass does not really provide any more help for what questions it should be use for:

> The parts of music that involves the lowest pitched voice in music;
>   usually referring to parts corresponding to bass vocalists, or below.

So how should this tag be used?

Comment: Very good call!

Comment: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/10/instrument-tagging-standards

Comment: I've even seen it used for bass drum in drumming questions!

Answer (score 8):

My suggestion is since the term bass covers a lot of different concepts and since  pretty much every use of the tag is covered by another tag we blacklist the bass tag.

If we really need a tag for the last two items on the list above we can create them to specifically cover the category of questions instead of using the broad bass tag.

Comment: Good call out, and a workable solution I think.

Comment: Do we have a [tag:treble] tag? No. Do we whence need a similar [tag:bass] tag? No.

Comment: @yo' but there is a [tag:melody] tag, [tag:bass] is, in a sense, the compliment of that.

Comment: @Dave not quite as you can have a treble line that is part of the [tag:harmony] which the bass is also a part of and which is the complement of melody.

Comment: @yo' Bass and treble are not exactly each other's counterpart in terms of their role in music. Questions asking about the role of the bass make sense, whereas questions asking about the treble tend to be confusing. There's no specialised knowledge that users would need to answer questions about treble, whereas for bass, that exists.

Answer (score 2):

This: [Is the bass line accompaniment in a song classed as its own melody / voice?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33643/is-the-bass-line-accompaniment-in-a-song-classed-as-its-own-melody-voice) is a question that, if we keep a [bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass), would fit, at it is about the "bass role" in a piece of music, and is at least somewhat independent of how it is instrumented.

Comment: It would certainly fit, but would it be useful?  That's generally a criterion for whether a tag should exist.  I'm not sure that it would actually be useful for filter harmony questions that are specifically about bass.

Comment: @MatthewRead mainly I'm just pointing out a potential use, and a question conforming to that use; I'm not strongly advocating that it be kept.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to have a `bass-line` tag for this scenario if we ever need to separate bass line creation from general harmony.