# Blacklist the [bass] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Re [this question](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2246/104) can we please blacklist the [bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bass) tag. It serves no purpose - all uses are now covered by other more specific tags.

Comment: I think you (someone) first have you remove the tag from the existing questions...

Comment: I've retagged a few that were obvious, don't want to clutter the front page.

Comment: I finished removing the remaining tagged questions today so as of now,there are no questions with the bass tag.

Comment: It sure would be mean of me to ask one right now.

Comment: Assuming this is still a 'live' discussion, 1) What do we gain from blacklisting the tag? 2) What would we use to tag questions about playing, mixing, composing bass parts when those questions aren't specific to a particular bass instrument?

Comment: @topomorto 1. Nobody can create the tag so we'll never have to deal with it coming up again. 2. See linked question. If we really need to specify something we can use a `bass-*` tag if needed, but bass alone is way too ambitious and was used extremely poorly in the past.

Comment: We're also planning to blacklist the [tag:music] after this one which just reared it's head again and has been [discussed before](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/698/do-we-need-a-music-tag), but this one has been pending longer. There will be another meta post to discuss that in a week or two.

Comment: As a bass player I fully support this.

Answer (score 6):

No mere *tag* can be all about that bass...

> Please use a more specific tag. [See meta for details](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/how-should-the-bass-tag-be-used)

The tag is henceforth disallowed, and attempts to use or recreate it will be blocked with the above message.

Answer (score 4):

> ....[the tag] was used extremely poorly in the past

The proof of the pudding is in the eating and if it hasn't worked, that seems like a good reason to get rid of it!

I do think there are further more specific bass-related tags that we might need to make, but as long as we are open to that I don't see any problem with blacklisting the [bass] tag.