# Should the [catholic-church] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

It looks like a user recently created the [catholic-church](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholic-church) tag just so that they could do a tag-edit on one of their own old questions. Someone has already removed the tag from the question, but do we even need this tag?

The obvious answer is that we don't need this tag that is not music-related, and certainly could never stand on its own to tag a question; in any case, we already have a [church-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-music) tag. I don't recall seeing discussions of tag burnination on SE Music Meta, so maybe this isn't something that we even worry about here.

Can we get rid of this tag?

Comment: Too soon, man. Too soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's already pretty much burned. It's not on any current questions, it has no valid wiki, and will be deleted tonight on the system cleaning.

It should be pointed out that it is not blacklisted yet nor will it likely be anytime soon. The blacklisting requires the community manager's intervention and the only time I can recall a tag being blacklisted on this site was the [bass tag](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/blacklist-the-bass-tag).

Comment: @DavidBowling that is my general understanding, but I'll find a post on meta SE to confirm the actual abandoned tag requirements.

Comment: @DavidBowling https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags is the first thing that comes up, but I think there is a better reference out there.

Comment: The wiki doesn't even matter if it's not on any questions. :) The wiki keeps a tag on a single question from being removed but that's it. As to blacklisting, we generally only blacklist in the case of tags that are being revived several times over. If you burn it and it stays gone, no need to blacklist. :D