# Should we 'fughetta' the fughetta tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Is there a reason we have a [fughetta](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fughetta) tag? There is only 1 question that uses it and it is about a Bach Fughetta. Still, wouldn't the [fugue](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fugue) tag be just as relevant to the question linked here:

[At what tempo would J.S.Bach play his fughettas?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/81124/at-what-tempo-would-j-s-bach-play-his-fughettas)

I mean, after all a fughetta simply means a small fugue. So do we really need [fughetta](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fughetta) when [fugue](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fugue) is just as relevant?

**I personally think that the fughetta tag is completely unnecessary and that we can do with just the fugue tag. Should we get rid of the fughetta tag?**

Comment: Apologies for the title change - someone led me astray....

Comment: @topomorto -- sorry about that; it was a moment of weakness ;)

Comment: @DavidBowling aaah, fughettabout it...

Comment: Surely you mean: "should we `fughetta`bout the `fughetta` tag?"

Comment: Related: http://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3259/should-the-catholic-church-tag-be-burninated

Answer (score 6):

Getting rid of it and replacing it with [fugue](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fugue) seems sensible to me. Tags that are too specific aren't very useful; There don't seem to be many (any?) other fughetta questions waiting to be tagged with this.

Comment: I feel like there was a missed opportunity in the question title: Should we "fughetta" about the `fughetta` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Since the votes seem to indicate that the community is in agreement with you, and no dissenting opinions have been offered here, I removed the [fughetta](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fughetta) tag from the only answer which had that tag, and replaced it with the [fugue](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fugue) tag. The tag was then deleted during the nightly system cleaning since it is no longer used on any questions. So, the [fughetta](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fughetta) tag is gone, for now.